# If condition inside for loop

Tags: javascript, servicenow

I want to get manager user from current user record. So i have created a `for` loop to get all the hierarchy from current users

Ex: if current current user Supervisor from my FORloop i will get the results like this

- Asst manager
- manager
- VP
- SVP
- CEO

From above loop i need to separate Manager and VP users so that's why i added `IF` condition to my `FOR` loop but looks like it's not working

```
var grnewreports= new GlideRecord('sys_user');
grnewreports.get('2f78075c13d99a0085b9da82e144b0f5');
generateApprovalNewNonMangament(grnewreports,5,'test')

function generateApprovalNewNonMangament(grnewreports, approvalLevel, approvalDescription) {
    try {

        var approvalUser = '';
        var manager1level = '';
        //var manager = '';
        for(var i = 1; i <= approvalLevel ; i++) {

            approvalUser = grnewreports.manager;
            gs.log('approval user:'+approvalUser,'TESTINSIDEIF');
            grnewreports = grnewreports.manager; // upgrading the level of user so that in next loop it should pick next level

            if(string[i].title == 'Managemnt') {
                var manager1 = string[i];
                var vp = manager1.manager;
            }

        }

    }
    catch(ex) {
    }
}
```

Please help me where i am doing wrong in script

Thanks,
Chaitanya

Comment: I am passing user record in function and from For loop i am getting the user hierarchy all the way to CEO. In Hierarchy i need to separateManager, VP users and store them separate variables.   Here is i am passing Sys Id of user record ----grnewreports.get('2f78075c13d99a0085b9da82e144b0f5');

Comment: I am passing user record in function and from For loop i am getting the user hierarchy all the way to CEO. In Hierarchy i need to separate Manager, VP users and store them separate variables.   Here is i am passing Sys Id of user record ----grnewreports.get('2f78075c13d99a0085b9da82e144b0f5');                          Above user is SUPVISOR and from FOR loop i will get the SYS ID s of ASST Manager, Manager, VP,SVP,CEO. From there i need to Extract the Manager , VP users from there that's why i added IF condition                       I am missing somethings in IF condition

Comment: Is the misspelling of `Managemnt` intentional  ... or should it be: **Management**?

Comment: I figured out the this issue. Have another question how do i declare array and keep the results from for loop into the array like from te above for loop i get the hierarchy of user and i want to store those results into array like this from for loop i get this Asst Mg, Manager, VP, SVP, CEO and i want to store them in like this [Asst Mg, Manager, VP, SVP, CEO]???

Comment: Are you trying to get an array of titles? It looks the loop and other handling is trying to get other info too?

Comment: I am trying to get users in array

Answer (score 0):

I believe your issue might be due to "pass-by-reference".

Here's an article I wrote which explains the issue, and how to fix it! 
https://snprotips.com/blog/2017/4/9/always-use-getters-and-setters

The short answer: Use **.getValue()** on lines 13, 15, and 19!